# Resizing images for display only

Tags: php, image, resize, gd

I've been doing a lot of research on this topic, though not all of what I find is central to my specific problem.

I was hired to rebuild a website for a friend, and this website has somewhere in the neighborhood of 20,000 images that are associated with 223 chapters. The chapters are displayed six per page, each chapter with a main image and descriptive text. The main image is randomly selected from the photos associated with each chapter. This all works fine.

The problem is this: These photos vary in size from 640x426 up to 929 x 622, and are saved as optimized for weband. Therefore, when you scroll through the page showing the chapters, the main images are (in most cases) different sizes and this looks not so good.

I'd like to stick with the randomly chosen image, but I'm not about to embark on resizing, and in some instances, cropping over 20,000 images. That's why I'd like to know if resizing the randomly selected images for display only would be a stupid idea. I have read some posts here and elsewhere that say not to do this.

However, doing this would solve my problem.

Again, the chapters are displayed 6 at a time, so there are 31 pages of them, and at any given time six images will need to be resized per user per page view. Part of me already knows this isn't the right approach, but I'd like some opinions from more knowledgeable PHP folks.

I have a dedicated server with GD installed, but not ImageMagick.

Many thanks!

Comment: Resizing and cropping 20,000 images shouldn't take too long, I'd go with that approach rather than redo such a task everytime an image is requested.

Comment: Well, I have to go through each of the image folders and determine which images can be resized automatically, and which need to be cropped. I see this taking at least a week.

Comment: I use phpThumb http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ for things like this.

Comment: @Brian I have seen that mentioned. I don't want to create thumbs, simply resize the randomly chosen image for display only, they won't be saved. Would phpthumb be good for that purpose?

Comment: It's easy to use, since you just tack on some parameters to the img src `?width=300` for example. It generates the re-sized image for you, and also caches it server-side for faster loading.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd grab [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) and have some fun with Batch resizing:

[image]